# Prolog unification exercise

Tags: prolog

I not shure how in my exam answer to this qestion:

> Let's consider this prolog program:

```
p(a,b).
p(b,c).
p(c,a).
q(X,X).
q(X,Y):-p(X,Z),q(Z,Y).
```

and question:

```
?- q(X,X).
```

And valid? answer is:

> Above aim is fulfilled in infinitely many ways, but none of them is
>   substitution X = b.

And I don't get it, really. IMO this predicate can be fullfilled in 3 ways:

```
 q(a,a) or  q(b,b) or  q(c,c).
```

What I don't understand here? Or maybe the answer is wrong and I just waste time and my answer is good?

Comment: The query is the same as one of the rules, so I think "infinitely many way" is correct. But there is nothing that prevents the substitution `X=b`.

Comment: But rules contain constants "a","b" and "c" and yeah rules are same as query so there should be only 3 answers IMO. Infinitely answers would be if p(A,B) and p(B,C) and p(C,A)  then q(X,X) would have infinitely many answers... but thats just my logic. Maybe it's different.

Comment: There is nothing preventing `q(d,d)` or `q(e,e)` to be evaluated to true. As long as the 2 arguments are the same, the query will satisfy the rule `q(X,X)`.

Comment: Right, so proper answer should be: "query have infinitely many results"

Comment: the question is, what happens when you issue the query `?- q(X,X).`. No `q(b,b)` will be ever produced. *Were you* to issue a query `?- q(b,b).` or `?- q(42,42).` the two would indeed succeed; but that is not what is asked.

Comment: @Naimads, as soon as you stipulated q(X,X). then you are saying "q(X,X) is true for ANY values of X". It doesn't matter whether that rule comes first or not. There is nothing in your rules that limits the instantiation of X to only those atoms which involve your p predicates, unless you said something like q(X,X) :- p(X,_). It's important to note that, in Prolog, multiple rules for a predicate indicate an OR condition. So your code says `q(X,X).` is true for any instantiation of `X`, OR `q(X,Y) :-...` is true. They don't limit conditions upon each other.

Answer (score 1):

The `q(X,X).` rule matches any input where the arguments to `q` are equal. You can easily try this out for yourself:

```
?- [user].
|: q(X, X).
|: q(X, Y) :- p(X, Z), q(Z, Y).
|: % user://1 compiled 0.00 sec, 1,808 bytes
true.

?- q(b, b).
true.

?- q(X, X), X=b.
X = b.
```

Instead of `b`, you can fill in any Prolog term in the final query. (Note that I haven't even entered the definition of `p` here; it's irrelevant.)

Comment: ah right, it's because q(X,X) is tried first so I can q(X,X) where X = any, but still this doesn't exclude X = b, so this so called "valid" answer is wrong.

Comment: @Naimads: it doesn't matter what is tried first. If the clauses were in reverse order, backtracking would find the reflexive clause. But the given answer seems to be incorrect.